# astype() does not respect given column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty dataframe with just the index as the columns are added during later steps.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

start = int(100E6)
stop = int(1E9)
step = int(1E6)

sweep = [*range(start, stop+step, step)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=sweep)

df[['Z0', 'eef']] = np.nan
for i in sweep:
    df.loc[i]['Z0'] = 50
    df.loc[i]['eef'] = 3

# Add columns 'A',... and the array
df[['A']] = 0
# df.A = df.A.astype(complex)

# for i in sweep:
#     df.loc[i]['A'] = 1j
df.loc[100000000]
```

This results in

```
Z0     50.0
eef     3.0
A       0.0
Name: 100000000, dtype: float64
```

However if I comment in the line `df.A = df.A.astype(complex)` this also alters `Z0` and `eef` to the following:

```
Z0     50.0+0.0j
eef     3.0+0.0j
A       0.0+0.0j
Name: 100000000, dtype: complex128
```

What is happening here? When I later work on the "altered" dataframe I get errors

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Comment: looks like a bug...might want to check if it's been reported to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas , and if not, to open a bug report

Comment: dtypes of cols Z0 and eef remain the same when commenting in the line you mentioned when I run your code. Also, I am able to alter values of the dataframe without any error or warning.

Comment: restart your console, it works perfectly fine here

Comment: @MichaelHodel Thank you for your reply. I updated all python(3) packages to be "up to date" but had no success with it. 

What OS are you using? I am running the current elementary os and I have the feeling there's something wrong here (might explain other issues I encounter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be raised by the way I access the dataframe in the for-loop. The console throws a warning and the provided [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) describes a more effective approach.

The following snippet works but pandas seems to alter the dtypes for efficiency:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=sweep)
df2[['Z0', 'eef']] = 1j
print(df2.dtypes)
for i in sweep:
    df2.loc[i:,('Z0')] = 1
    df2.loc[i:,('eef')] = 1.0
print(df2.dtypes)
```

To be honest, I have no idea why I need to slice the frame to write to it but *not* when reading.

```
Z0     complex128
eef    complex128
dtype: object
Z0       int64
eef    float64
dtype: object
```